# What does the perm_invK lemma in Ssreflect prove?

Tags: permutation, coq, theorem-proving, ssreflect

The following code is from `perm.v` in the Ssreflect Coq library. 
I want to know what this result is.

```
Lemma perm_invK s : cancel (fun x => iinv (perm_onto s x)) s.
Proof. by move=> x /=; rewrite f_iinv. Qed.
```

Answer (score 4):

Definitions in Ssreflect can involve lots of concepts, and sometimes it is hard to understand what is actually going on. Let's analyze this by parts.

`iinv` (defined in `fintype.v`) has type

```
iinv : forall (T : finType) (T' : eqType) (f : T -> T') 
              (A : pred T) (y : T'),
         y \in [seq f x | x in A] -> T
```

What this does is to invert any function `f : T -> T'` whose restriction to a subdomain `A \subset T` is surjective on `T'`. Put in other words, if you give me an `y` that is in the list of results of applying `f` to all elements of `A`, then I can find you an `x \in A` such that `f x = y`. Notice that this relies crucially on the fact that `T` is a finite type and that `T'` has decidable equality. The correctness of `iinv` is stated in lemma `f_iinv`, which is used above.

`perm_onto` has type `codom s =i predT`, where `s` is some permutation defined on a finite type `T`. This is saying, as its name implies, that `s` is surjective (which is obvious, since it is injective, by the definition of permutations in `perm.v`, and by the fact that the domain and codomain are the same). Thus, `fun x => iinv (perm_onto s x)` is a function that maps an element `x` to an element `y` such that `s y = x`. In other words, its the inverse of `s`. `perm_invK` is simply stating that this function is indeed the inverse (to be more precise, it is saying that it is the left inverse of `s`).

The definition that is actually useful, however, is `perm_inv`, which appears right below. What it does is that it packages `fun x => iinv (perm_onto s x)` with its proof of correctness `perm_invK` to define an element of `perm_inv s` of type `{perm T}` such that `perm_inv s * s = s * perm_inv s = 1`. Thus, you can view it as saying that the type `{perm T}` is closed under inverses, which allows you to use a lot of the ssr machinery for e.g. finite groups and monoids.